# Date Comparion in DMN - Decision Table

Tags: drools, dmn

Using `jbpm version 7`

DataModel :: Profile has two fields
( `onboarding` of type `date` , `currentDate` of type `date`)

When I am writing Decision Table : it keeps throwing Error `Skipped Decision Table Analysis of table 'onBoardingDateDecision' because: Gaps/Overlaps analysis cannot be performed for InputEntry with unary test`

Why I am not able to perform Date Comparios in Decision Table ?

If I give simple expression like > date("2005-01-01") it works !

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The message "`Skipped Decision Table Analysis ... Gaps/Overlaps ...`" refers to ***static analysis***.

It does NOT affect any ***runtime*** behaviour and the Drools DMN Engine can evaluate your model as you would normally expect.

Gap/Overlap static analysis cannot be performed with the variable expressions in your table, hence it is skipped, and the message reports this accordingly.

Comment: I solved it using Literal Expression and not Decision Table

Comment: If there was only 1 condition then yes, I believe it would be more DMN-idiomatic. Glad if I helped @user1428716